Using piezo as range sensor
My objective is to use a single piezo as a transceiver and calculate the distance between the sensor and the object that sound echos from using time of fly. I use tone() function or manually create square wave to the piezo, but after transmitting all I see on the oscilloscope screen is noise. Without Arduino there is not that much noise. How can I detect the echo?

Schematic, please ...

Are you measuring distance in air/water/other? Have you verified that the piezo element is able to "recieve" the echo or some other equivalent sound? I imagine you'd require amplification and something a lot less squishy than air. You'll also likely have significant error in your results (due to timing) if you plan to use the Arduino framework and its tone() function...

I expect you will need a microphone to receive the sound with any usable signal-to-noise.

No schematichs yet i started yet and trying to discover

I do measure in air

Piezo transducers are generally quite resonant; are you sure you are driving it with the correct frequency?

Seller says mid frequency is around 4khz

Try to receive the transmitted signal with a second piezo connected to the scope. Then you will see how weak the signal is. This probably will not work at all. Is is difficult to suppress the ringing of the piezo after the transmission burst before the echo with less than a mV comes in.

@alidemir 4 kHz, or 40 kHz? A 4 kHz piezo electric transducer would be fairly thick and uncommon. 40 kHz is very common. What does your transmit/receive (T/R) circuit look like? If you are using a flat smooth surface, angular alignment needs to be fairly precise.

Actually im pllaning to use an 40khz but currently i do have 4khz and i was Just trying to see if im could see the echo onboard

I do not have an impedance match or switch circuit yet , could you help or lead me ?

@alidemir As others have stated, show a schematic or a block diagram of what you have tried. Without the schematic, it is difficult to help you.

I do not have schematic yet still designing.

Even though you want to end up with same piezo for both Tx & Rx, using two piezos of the same kind may be helpful because you can try some tests using constant tones. That can help you to work on echo as stage two of design. And may also enable your first schematic.
